# How to determine the rank(A), if diagonal entries of R matrix of it's QR factorisation has k non zero elements.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I understand that when a $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with $m>n$ has full rank, then the diagonal entries of its $R$ matrix from its reduced QR factorisation are all non-zero.

But I saw a literature online, which extended this; and said when only $'k'$ diagonal entries of matrix $R$ are non zero, then $k\leq\operatorname{rank}(A)< n $ ; I don't understand the proof of this statement.

From my understanding; each non-zero diagonal entry of $R$ from reduced QR factorisation of $A$, means that there is a vector in $\operatorname{col}(A)$ which is linearly dependent on the rest of the independent basis! Thus; we must have $n-k$ linearly dependent vectors in the $\operatorname{col}(A)$.

Comment: *"each non-zero diagonal entry of  from reduced QR factorisation of , means that there is a vector in col() which is linearly dependent on the rest of the independent basis!"* -- this does not make sense.  a non-zero diagonal entry in a (not necessarily square) upper triangular matrix indicates linear independence of said column compare to all columns to the left of it.  A zero on the diagonal may or may not indicate linear dependence.  Please post a few example where of $3\times 3$ matrices so we can see what work you've done.

Comment: @user8675309 Yes, you are correct! Any $k+1$th diagonal element in the upper triangular matrix means that the linear independence of that column with respect to the all the columns on the left of that column! So we see only k columns of A which are linearly independent, right? So should the rank not be 'k'. I wish to prove this with concepts of linear algebra rather than through examples; that's why I have not included any example like $3x3$

Comment: @user8675309 I can't see how that will help? Still I'll do that since you recommend. $ A $ = [ 1 -2 -2; 0 1 1; 3 2 2; 1 4 4];  , $rank(A) = 2$ , $diag(R) = {-3.3 , -4.3 , 0}$. Here I have chosen the last column to be dependent on first 2. Now how to go about and prove $ ≤ rank()<  $ when k = 2 for this case? In which case can $rank(A)$ be greater than $k$?

Comment: @user8675309 Shall I post more examples?

Comment: You should post them in the original post in LaTeX.  What you've done in comments is unreadable.  There is no need to look at $A$ or $Q$ per se-- you just need to write out examples for various $R$'s (suggestion: $4\times 3$ matrices) and consider rank properties of (not necessarily square) upper triangular matrices.  I take it for granted that you understand $\text{rank}\big(A\big) = \text{rank}\big(QR\big)= \text{rank}\big(R\big)$